# Configure MobileFirst Analytics to not print the Adapter Procedure Arguments

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

I am using MF 7.0 and have configured the MF Analytics for the server. Everything is working just fine but I one have question over the logs collection mechanism of the MF Analytics. In my adapter I have following procedure defined for user to login:

```
<procedure name="login"/>

function(userId,passKey){
        var jsonLoginParms = JSON.stringify({username: userId, password: passKey});

        var input = {
            method : 'post',
            returnedContentType : jsonContentType,
            path : "login",
            body :{
                contentType: jsonHeader,
                content:jsonLoginParms
            }

        };
        response = WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
    }
```

This procedure accepts **username** and **password** to authenticate the user over RESTful WebService. When the rest call is over, if I go to Analytics --> Search --> Server log Search and look for the logs, its prints the password in plain text (I haven't print the username/password anywhere). Is there anyway I configure this to not print the adapter procedure arguments?

Following is the screenshot of it:
[image]

Comment: Do you have audit=true in your procedure declaration inside adapter.xml file ?

Comment: What is the level of logging that you are collecting on your server?

Comment: I haven't configured anything separately for Analytics. In server.xml I have following entry for logging : <logging consoleLogLevel="INFO" copySystemStreams="false"/>, But this controls the console log not the one which is getting pushed into Analytics.

Comment: Can you copy/paste your server.xml and your adapter.xml? The only time I see this is when I set my logging to be verbose.

Comment: I have only these 2 statements in server.xml which are related to logging: <logging maxFileSize="20" maxFiles="10" traceFileName="trace.log" traceFormat="BASIC" traceSpecification="com.worklight.*=all"/>
    <logging consoleLogLevel="INFO" copySystemStreams="false"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analytics console is collecting data from the MobileFirst Platform Foundation server. When you perform the:

```
WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
```

All from that call is collected and forwarded to the analytics server.

Increase the logging verbosity and you will no longer see FINE logs showing up.

Example:

```
<logging traceSpecification="com.worklight.*=FATAL=enabled"/>
```